# C# UWP MySql BulkLoader - Unable to load data using csv

Tags: c#, mysql, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm having trouble loading data from csv into mysql database using UWP application.
What I'm basically trying to do is:

- Read the data from the csv file via HttpClient (200k records, 32 megabytes)
- Save the data into a csv file in my application's temp folder
- Read the file and identify the columns that need to be inserted
- Use the MySqlBulkLoader class to load the csv into the database

Below is the code that I'm trying:

```
public static async Task<int> MemberEnrollment_GetFromServer_FirstSync(string _url)
{
    int insertedRecords = 0;
    string csv_data = await DownloadDataAsync(_url);

    //StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder;
    //StorageFile csv = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + ".csv", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    StorageFile csv = await DownloadsFolder.CreateFileAsync(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + ".csv");

    var token = Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(csv);

    try
    {
        await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(csv, csv_data, Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8);

        var testRead = await OpenFile(csv.Path, FileAccess.Read);

        //batch insert into the memberenrollment table
        insertedRecords = await DataServices.MemberEnrollment_PostToLocal_Bulk(csv);
    }
    catch (Exception exInsertBatch)
    {
        throw exInsertBatch;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (File.Exists(csv.Path))
            await csv.DeleteAsync(StorageDeleteOption.PermanentDelete);
    }
    return insertedRecords;
}
private static async Task<string> DownloadDataAsync(string url)
    {
        string data = string.Empty;
        using (HttpClient Client = GetHttpClient())
        {
            Client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
            data = await Client.GetStringAsync(url);
        }
        return data;
    }
private async static Task<Stream> OpenFile(string path, FileAccess access)
{
    StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(path);
    if (access == FileAccess.Read)
        return await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
    else
        return await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
}

public static async Task<int> MemberEnrollment_PostToLocal_Bulk(StorageFile File)
{
    int result = 0;
    List<string> columns = new List<string>();
    List<string> expressions = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        //read the column names
        var lines = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(File, Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8);
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            //columns = string.Join(",", line.Replace("\"", "").Split(new char[] { '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
            string[] arrHeaders = line.Replace("\"", "").Split(new char[] { '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            foreach (string header in arrHeaders)
            {
                columns.Add(header);
            }

            break;
        }
        result = await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            return DataLayer.MemberEnrollment_Write_Bulk(File.Path, columns, expressions);
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    return result;
}


public static int MemberEnrollment_Write_Bulk(string FilePath,List<string> columns,List<string> expressions)
{
    int result = 0;
    using (MySqlConnection con = DataProvider.GetConnection())
    {
        MySqlBulkLoader mySqlBulkLoader = new MySqlBulkLoader(con);
        //mySqlBulkLoader.CharacterSet = "utf8";
        mySqlBulkLoader.FieldQuotationCharacter = '"';
        mySqlBulkLoader.Expressions.AddRange(expressions);
        //mySqlBulkLoader.EscapeCharacter = '\\';
        //mySqlBulkLoader.FieldTerminator = "\t";
        mySqlBulkLoader.FileName = FilePath;
        mySqlBulkLoader.LineTerminator = "\\r\\n";
        mySqlBulkLoader.NumberOfLinesToSkip = 1;
        mySqlBulkLoader.TableName = "AC_Memberenrollment";
        mySqlBulkLoader.Timeout = 120;
        mySqlBulkLoader.Columns.AddRange(columns);
        result = mySqlBulkLoader.Load();
    }
    return result;
}
```

As soon as the debugger hits the

```
result = mySqlBulkLoader.Load();
```

line, it throws the below error:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException occurred
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) in C:\Users\ramesh\Downloads\MySql.Data.UWP-master\MySql.Data.UWP-master\MySql.Data.UWP\command.cs:line 545
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader() in C:\Users\ramesh\Downloads\MySql.Data.UWP-master\MySql.Data.UWP-master\MySql.Data.UWP\command.cs:line 397
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() in C:\Users\ramesh\Downloads\MySql.Data.UWP-master\MySql.Data.UWP-master\MySql.Data.UWP\command.cs:line 340
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlBulkLoader.Load() in C:\Users\ramesh\Downloads\MySql.Data.UWP-master\MySql.Data.UWP-master\MySql.Data.UWP\BulkLoader.cs:line 277
   at Controller.DAL.DataLayer.MemberEnrollment_Write_Bulk(String FilePath, List`1 columns, List`1 expressions) in E:\Work\Controller\DAL\DataLayer.cs:line 344
   at Controller.Classes.DataServices.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<MemberEnrollment_PostToLocal_Bulk>b__0() in E:\Work\Controller\Classes\DataServices.cs:line 1333
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

Inner Exception 1: MySqlException: Fatal error encountered attempting
 to read the resultset.

Inner Exception 2: MySqlException: Error during LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Inner Exception 3: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to
an instance of an object.
```

To understand the actual reason, I had downloaded the source code of the MySql.Data.UWP.dll from https://github.com/nudaca/MySql.Data.UWP and found out that the actual issue occurs while trying to open the csv file in FileStream.cs at function

```
private async void OpenFile(string path, FileAccess access)
{
  StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(path);//<--error here
  if (access == FileAccess.Read)
    stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
  else
    stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
}
```

and the actual error is "Access is Denied"!

When I execute the command string generated from the SqlCommand in Workbench, it loads the data successfully.

I have enabled the capabilities in the Package.manifest for Internet(Client), Private Network(Client & Server) and Removable Storage.

I searched various posts and did try all the solutions, like so:

- [UWP UnauthorizedException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32538658/uwp-unauthorizedexception)
- [FileStream "access is denied" error all of a sudden](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d000273a-f68d-400e-893c-681edcd31c23/filestream-access-is-denied-error-all-of-a-sudden?forum=csharpgeneral)
- [Access to file in UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35681017/access-to-file-in-uwp)
- [Windows 10 Universal App File/Directory Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33082835/windows-10-universal-app-file-directory-access/33083243#33083243)

I've spent a long time before posting this here and ripped a portion of my fertile scalp while scratching my head to resolve this issue. Please help me out to bulk insert the data!

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you create the StorageFile **csv** file in the [DownloadsFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.downloadsfolder) and use the file **path** to get the file in the **OpenFile** method. 
UWP applications run sandboxed and have very limited access to the file system and StorageItems(i.e. StorageFolder and StorageFile) are the canonical storage identifiers for Windows Store apps, not the path. See Rob's blog [Skip the path: stick to the StorageFile](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2012/12/04/skip-the-path-stick-to-the-storagefile/).

As for your issue, you can try to use the **LocalFolder** instead of the [DownloadsFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.downloadsfolder), because the data that are stored in our local folder (ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder), we can use the path. See [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) to learn more about the file system locations that UWP apps can access.

Comment: hi, I am using a third party dll (MySql.Data.RT) for connecting the local mysql database. Sadly, the MySqlBulkUploader class requires the string path of the file, not the StorageFile. The actual error is at the line 
`StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(path);`
in the function **OpenFile**. (edited the question).
As for the location of saving the file, I had tried LocalFolder, RoamingFolder and the LocalTemp folder as well. But none of them worked (it still lies there in the code comment).

Comment: If you only replace the code  `StorageFile csv = await DownloadsFolder.CreateFileAsync(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + ".csv");` with `StorageFile csv = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + ".csv");` still have the error "Access is Denied"?

Comment: Yes. It still persists. If I create a uwp project in the solution of the source code of the MySql.Data.UWP (i did not get the source code of MySql.Data.RT, but assume it is to be same), and call the MySqlBulkUploader.Load() function with the same code, it works fine in the Debug mode, but throws the same error in the Release mode.

Comment: If convenient, could you share a minimal reproducing project to help me see it?

Comment: I might take a _long_ while to create a test project as i'll be travelling in some time and would not be back until Monday. Really sorry for that.